# I had a JSON with font. need to parse into its font and display in textview

Tags: android, json, fonts

I had a JSON with font in mangal.tff. need to parse its and should display with its fonts textview but the fonts in textviews are in unreadable format.

my code for android

```
  try {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");       

for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                                        String title =   newsValue.getString("title");
                                        String imageresource = newsValue.getString("image");
                                        String description = newsValue.getString("description");

                                        NewsData newsData = new NewsData();

                                        newsData.setDesc(description);
                                        newsData.setTitle(title);
                                        newsData.setNewsImage(imageresource);
                                        newsDatas.add(newsData)
                                    }
                                    newsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

[my JSON strucutre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwvKA.png)

Comment: What you tried to read font?

Comment: put your font  (mangal.tff) in the assets of your project to follow @user2025187 answer

Comment: done that. but cannot get font in readable

Answer (score 2):

Your Json parsing not correct

Set the font type to textview

```
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/yourFont.TTF");
```

Try this,

```
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
        for (int i =0;i<jsonArray.length();i++) {

            JSONObject obj=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String title = obj.getString("title");
            String imageresource = obj.getString("image");
            String description = obj.getString("description");

            NewsData newsData = new NewsData();

            newsData.setDesc(description);
            newsData.setTitle(title);
            newsData.setNewsImage(imageresource);
            newsDatas.add(newsData);

        }
        newsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: DONE THAT, there was no issue in json parsing. i got a all values, but not in a readbale format.